# Buscar valores en un arreglo VB

Tags: array, vb.net, vb

estoy haciendo una tarea para buscar datos en un arreglo, en este ejemplo tengo un arreglo con valores 01, 02, y 03.

Lo que hago es colocar un valor en una caja de texto y en una función **BuscarClaves** indicar si ese valor existe en el arreglo. 
No se en qué puedo estar equivocado ya que solo me toma el primer valor del arreglo y por lo tanto me imprime el mismo mensaje siempre.

Este es el código que tengo.

```
 Dim VectorA() As String = {"01", "02", "03"}

    Public Function buscarClaves(ByVal dts As String) As Boolean
        'buscarClaves = False
        For Each clave As String In VectorA
            If clave = dts Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        '
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To VectorA.Length
            If buscarClaves(TextBox1.Text) Then
                MsgBox("Clave duplicado")
            Else
                MsgBox("Clave disponible")
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El for en el evento del Button está de más, ya que tienes un For Each que recorre todo el array en la función, por eso te repite el mismo valor en el mensaje, porque siempre encuentra la clave en los tres recorridos que hace por la longitud del array.

Y le hice algunos cambios a la función buscarClaves(). Si encuentra el valor retorna true, sino simplemente tomará el valor que le diste al inicio, no es necesario agregar el else con el return false.

```
Public Class Form1
   Private VectorA() As String = {"01", "02", "03"}
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Try
         If buscarClaves(TextBox1.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Clave duplicado")
         Else
            MsgBox("Clave disponible")
         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex)
      End Try
   End Sub
   Public Function buscarClaves(ByVal dts As String) As Boolean
      buscarClaves = False
      For Each clave As String In VectorA
         If clave = dts Then
            Return True
         End If
      Next
   End Function
End Class
```